# Automatically populate HATEAOS links using JAXB or something similar?

Tags: java, rest, jaxb, hateoas

Let's say I'm following HATEOAS and using hypertext in my XML. Something like this:

/customer/32

```
<Customer>
  <FirstName>Joe</FirstName>
  <LastName>Smith</LastName>
  <Address href="/address/4324">
</Customer>
```

/address/4324

```
<Address>
  <Street>123 Fake St</Street>
  <Town>Springfield</Town>
</Address>
```

Is there a library akin to or an extension of JAXB that can unmarshall a Customer and automatically query for and unmarshall Address as a property of that Customer (like `customer.getAddress().getStreet()`)? If not, what's a good approach to this that lends itself to client-side caching?

Comment: how did you generate the href property on the Address class?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In JAXB you could use an XmlAdapter for this use case.  The XmlAdapter would specify value type String and bound type Address.  The you would add the logic to convert between them.

For More Info

- http://bdoughan.blogspot.com/2010/07/xmladapter-jaxbs-secret-weapon.html?m=1

Comment: Is that going to work if I am generating my classes with XJC? Would I need a schema element that's a link/address choice? Or does the schema only need to match the transformed state?

Comment: @Jiggy - I would recommend modifying the generated source code to add in the XmlAdapter.

Comment: @BlaiseDoughan, let me make sure that I understand.  Customer class has a getAddress() method; the getAddress() method has @XmlJavaTypeAdapter(AddressAdapter.class) annotation; the Address class' properties are annotated `@XmlElement' and `@XmlValue`.  Process: AddressAdapter.unmarshall() method makes GET call to /address/4324 to get XML rendering, generates/returns an instance of the Address class, which is then returns the street via getStreet().  Is this correct?